# Add directory to all PATH-like variables

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, path

Is there a function that can add a root folder to all path-like variables? At the moment I use this function:

```
function prepend_paths() {
    ROOT_PATH=$(readlink -f $1)
    export PATH=$ROOT_PATH/bin:$PATH
    export LD_LIBARY_PATH=$ROOT_PATH/lib:$LD_LIBARY_PATH
    export LD_LIBARY_PATH=$ROOT_PATH/lib64:$LD_LIBARY_PATH
    export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$ROOT_PATH/include:$C_INCLUDE_PATH
    export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$ROOT_PATH/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
    export PYTHONPATH=$ROOT_PATH/lib/python3.5/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
    export MANPATH=$ROOT_PATH/share/man:$MANPATH
}
```

But I don't know if it is exhaustive.

I can't be the only one who'd like this kind of function every now and then, so I figure must be some pre-existing way to do this. I haven't been able to find any so far though.

Comment: Related: [Add directory to ``$PATH`` if it's not already there](https://superuser.com/a/39995/354511).

Comment: Can you clarify what constitutes a "path-like" variable? Ones that end in "PATH"?

Comment: This question seems to be to be a classic example of the XY Problem. @Jens: please read this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. And tell us precisely what you're trying to solve. Since what you're currently attempting to do doesn't seem to make much sense to me.

Comment: How does it not make sense? Say you are installing some libraries or programs to a prefixed location, can you set all path-like variables so that you can run anything in bin, include anything in include, link anything in lib, etc. Pretty much the same way Linux already sets up a few folders and variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `export` is different from assignment. It sounds like you want to do the following

```
function prepend_paths() {
    for P in $(env | grep PATH | sed 's/=.*//') ; do
        eval $P=${1}:\$$P ;
    done
}
```

I.e., prepend the given prefix to all environment variables with "PATH" in their name. The embedded `$(env ..)` sub command provides that list of variable names. The working line, in the body of the for loop, performs the assignment via the `eval` call, which conveniently performs the double evaluation of `P` (first into the variable name, the into the value of that variable).

Those assignments would then be held in "this shell", and all variables that are already marked as "exported" will be propagted to sub processes. You can of course add explicit `export $P` statements if you wish, as well as print-out to report the assignments if you feel that's a good thing.

Comment: This seems a little sketchy, but would solve my problem. It is the best solution I've seen so far though

Answer (score -1):

The question if "this is exhaustive?" is intriguing. How can this list of `PATH`-like variables ever be exhaustive? You mention `PATH` above, which is honored by most shells. And `LD_LIBARY_PATH` is honored by most programs too. And `PYTHONPATH` is indeed honored by the Python executable. But since you don't know which program you're going to install tomorrow, how can you know before which `PATH`-like variable to set?

Java comes to mind, with `CLASSPATH`, and there's `su` with `ENV_ROOTPATH`. But let's make up the hypothetical program `foo.exe` that honors `SOME_WEIRD_PATH_VARIABLE_NAME` - how can we know about this variable before? And maybe some other program honors another `PATH`-like variable called `PATH_SET` but doesn't expect this variable to be set to a *file path* but maybe expects it to be set to `1` or `0`. We don't what `PATH_SET` to be set to `pwd`, hm? :-)

Comment: Good point, in this case I would only assume there was a solution for all standard paths used in Linux development